# Migrate old custom patches to new Linux versions

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

I previously used Linux 3.0.35 to customize the OS for an IMX based board. I'm now planning to upgrade it to Linux 3.10.17. The customization was compiled into patches, (80+ patches!).

My problem now is what would be the fastest and safest way to apply these to the new Kernel? The only way I could think of is manually inserting the contents of each of these patches. Perhaps there is some `git` or `diff` command option that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `quilt` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilt_%28software%29) - that's the tool for managing and forward porting patches. Happily used by many distribution package maintainers, including maintainers of distribution kernels.

However there may be significant differences between 3.0.35 and 3.10.17 - forward porting may not be straightforward. The best approach may be to go release by release, 3.0.35 -> 3.1.0 -> 3.2.0 -> ... -> 3.10.x and make sure your patches work (not only compile) after every upgrade.